# Background with lower opacity without affecting content (and without using pseudo-elements)

Tags: html, css

How to have a background-image opacity 0.5 without affecting the contents of the `<p>`

```
<div class="div_with_background_image">
    <p>content</p>
</div>
```

The question is : is it possible to do that like that ?

**EDIT :**

Below is what I have currently and as can be seen the `opacity` is affecting the content of the `p`.

```css
div {
  background-image: url("http://biendansmacuisine.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/2013-04-02-21.29.15.jpg");
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
p {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    content with non opatity
  </p>
</div>
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/6nw6cezb/

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more on what you are looking for? The content and title are very unclear. Do you mean to say you want a background-image to have `opacity: 0.5` without using pseudo-elements?

Comment: You can add another div instead of `:before`.

Comment: What's `:before`, `:after`, and `<p>` got to do with background transparency?

Comment: Please supply all the details regarding the issue with a meaningful title. This is not a forum...it's above that in content quality

Comment: I edit my post with a link jsfiddle

Comment: @Greg: I've added the code from the fiddle into the question and also added a bit of description (based on my understanding). Validate if it matches your needs (and edit if it doesn't). I've also voted to reopen.

Comment: CSS Tricks has a [nice method](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/) to have a background that leverages the `opacity` property.  Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/yp527me5/

Comment: yes, but use pseudo-elements), look title :)

Comment: @Greg: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/6nw6cezb/3/) is the solution. Can't post now because the question is on hold. Will post as answer when it gets reopened. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it (without using any pseudo or extra elements) by placing a `linear-gradient` image that is nothing but a layer of semi-transparent white color (alpha = 0.5) on top of the image.

This will not affect the contents of the `p` tag also because it is still just a background image layer and nothing more than that. Note that the actual background image should be given after the gradient layer because CSS renders the last one (in the comma separated list) as the lower-most layer.

```css
.div_with_background_image {
  background:  linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)),
               url(http://placeimg.com/400/400/animals);
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
p {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div_with_background_image">
  <p>some content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is actually VERY USEFUL. +1 thx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give transparency to a background you can use pseudo-elements:

```css
.div_with_background_image {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.div_with_background_image:after {
  background: url(http://www.animalclan.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/noticias_48_1390596377.jpg) no-repeat center center / cover;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="div_with_background_image">
  <p>content</p>
</div>
```

Notice 3 things:

1. pseudoelement must have absolute positioning.
2. pseudoelement has z-index:-1.
3. the element you want to give that background must have position:relative.